# Outlook autofill subject line with specific text from body email

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, auto-form-fill

When someone fills out the "Contact Us" form on our company website, it arrives to me as an email to our generic email box.

[Here is an example of the email I receive.][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S53HO.jpg

I then reply back to that email and I'd like to autofill the subject line with content from within the email. I currently have a Quick Step that replaces the subject line with just "Web Inquiry - " and I copy/paste the person's first and last name, but I'd like to automate it a step further to automatically include those fields from the email body.  I'm trying to find a VBA/script/Quick Steps so that when I click the button:

1. a reply email is created and replaces/creates the subject line field as "Web Inquiry - First1 Last1"

and

2. IF POSSIBLE, it also enters the email address from the email body into the "To:" field

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You may go to Outlook for developer forum for more information.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you have submitted a post, you have licensed the content to the Super User community at large ([under the CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to actually modify the email your contact form sends. By populating the subject already as "Web Inquiry - *First1* *Last1*" your reply subject in Outlook would be "Re: Web Inquiry - *First1* *Last1*" by default.

The correct *To* field could also be accomplished by modifying the email the contact form sends — add a `Reply-To` header with the sender's email address. Some may advise the `From` header could also be set, but this should be avoided since it can lead to issues when SPF/DMARC is implemented on the sender's domain and can result in emails being sent to junk/quarantine or being rejected entirely since they are being "spoofed" by your web server.

How you would make these changes depends on your website CMS / contact form script. I'm unable to glean what it is by your screenshot. It may be as simple as changing some settings in the admin side of your website or as complicated as enlisting in the help of your web developer to make the changes.